# Node package wont run second command in Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running VSCode on Windows for a node application.  In my package.json file, I have the following scripts:

```
"dev": "npm run watch:ts & npm run run:nodemon",
"run:nodemon": "nodemon --legacy-watch --config nodemon.json",
"watch:ts": "onchange -v -i -p 100 \"./src/**/*.ts\" -- tsc --watch"
```

When I run it on Linux both commands will run.

```
npm run dev
```

But when I run it on Windows, only the first command works.  I changed the order and nodemon will run, but now the typescript watch won't.

This is the output running the original command

[image]

This is the output when I change the order to run nodemon first

[image]

Any ideas on what could be causing this or a solution to fix it?

**Update**
Thanks to Phil, I ended up using concurrently package

```
"dev": "concurrently  \"npm run watch:ts\" \"npm run run:nodemon\"",
```